# Binding to Bootstrap radio button state change

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Bootstrap HTML in a page that also uses jQuery:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
    <button id="copyButton" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Copy</button>
    <button id="editButton" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Modify</button>
    <button class="btn btn-small btn-primary active">Do nothing</button>
</div>
```

These three buttons appear on every row of a table (for each row the user must choose an action).

I would like to display and update a counter of the number of rows where the `Copy` button is active and the number of rows where the `Modify` button is active.

I have tried adding the following function which is called by a button-type specific function bound to the `click` event of the buttons:

```
function updateCounts() {
    var modifyValueCount = $("button[id=editButton].active").length;
    var copyValueCount = $("button[id=copyButton].active").length;
    $("#variablesToModifyCount").text(modifyValueCount);
    $("#variablesToCopyCount").text(copyValueCount);
}
```

But it seems to me that the button that has just been clicked doesn't get included in the count as the `active` class isn't applied until after the end of the invocation of `onClick`. I have also tried binding to the `mouseup` event but it also seems too soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to check if it is already active when clicking. So it doesn't really solve the problem with being notified about the active of bootstrap but is a workaround for your example,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        if ($(this).is("#editButton")) {
            if (!$(this).is("#editButton.active")) {
                updateCounts(1, 0);
            } else {
                updateCounts(-1, 0);
            }
        } else if ($(this).is("#copyButton")) {
            if (!$(this).is("#copyButton.active")) {
                updateCounts(0, 1);
            } else {
                updateCounts(0, -1);
            }
        }
    });


});

function updateCounts(changeEdit, changeCopy) {
    var modifyValueCount = parseFloat($("#variablesToModifyCount").text()) + changeEdit;
    var copyValueCount = parseFloat($("#variablesToCopyCount").text()) + changeCopy;
    $("#variablesToModifyCount").text(modifyValueCount < 0 ? 0 : modifyValueCount);
    $("#variablesToCopyCount").text(copyValueCount < 0 ? 0 : copyValueCount);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HWfVN/

**EDIT**
This is based on bootstrap2.3.2 and the toggle behaviour not checkbox as above,
(very rough implementation just providing an example of ***checking if the class active does not exist on click in order to act accordingly***)

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#variablesToModifyCount").text($("button[id=editButton].active").length);
    $("#variablesToCopyCount").text($("button[id=copyButton].active").length);

    $('button').on('click', function () {
        updateCounts($(this).is("#editButton") && !$(this).is("#editButton.active"),
        $(this).is("#copyButton") && !$(this).is("#copyButton.active"),
                     !$(this).is('#editButton')&&!$(this).is('#copyButton'));
    });


});

function updateCounts(incrementEdit, incrementCopy, decrementAll) {
    var modifyValueCount = $("button[id=editButton].active").length;
    var copyValueCount = $("button[id=copyButton].active").length;
    if(incrementEdit){
        modifyValueCount++;
        copyValueCount--;
    }
    if(incrementCopy){
        copyValueCount++;
        modifyValueCount--;
    }
    if(decrementAll){
        copyValueCount--;
        modifyValueCount--;
    }

    $("#variablesToModifyCount").text(modifyValueCount < 0 ? 0 : modifyValueCount);
    $("#variablesToCopyCount").text(copyValueCount < 0 ? 0 : copyValueCount);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HWfVN/3/

Comment: What happens if the user clicks an already-active button? Won't the count for that button go down?

Comment: Yes it will go down. Is this what you are aiming for? Oh you mean it is not counted in the first place. Indeed you could just count them initially, i can update that for you. Just tried to elaborate on the concept of checking the opposite state of class active, instead of looking for a notifications. It seems that others had similar trouble in the past https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/2380

Comment: If I click on a Radio Button twice, the first time round it goes in, the second time it does nothing. But the count will go up and then down. I need the count to reflect the number of buttons that are in...

Comment: When you first click a button, it goes in so it gets added. If you press it again, it goes out so it is subtracted. Isn't this the behaviour on the fiddle? i also updated it to include initial states. http://jsfiddle.net/HWfVN/1/

Comment: It's strange, your code in the fiddle is exhibiting the `data-toggle="buttons-checkbox"` behaviour whereas I want the `data-toggle="buttons-radio"` behaviour. I must admit I don't understand why, your code is just like mine. Just to be clear I don't want the user to be able to get into the situation where no button in a group is in.

Comment: Ok i see now, i actually judged by that behaviour and this happened because i was using bootstrap3, let me update and also add the edit on the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I haven't precisely used your answer, but it has explained how to solve the problem!